# How to check if an IC is fried?

Tags: integrated-circuit, breadboard, testing, test-equipment

I was using my 74173 (d-type register) today and accidentally attached the vcc pin to ground and the ground pin to 5v.  I didn't realize this and turned on the power.  A couple seconds after turning it on smoke started to come out of the IC so I turned it off.  I touched the IC a couple seconds after turning off the power and it was so hot it burned my finger a little.  What I am wondering is what is the best way to check if this IC is fried?  I could plug it in and see if it seems like it is behaving normal, but I am afraid that even if it works in my tests it may still have an edge case that it is broken for.  Basically I want to know if there is any way to check if the IC is 100% functional still instead of just making sure it still works with the cases you test it.

Comment: It smoked, how can anyone convince you it's 100% ok? Toss it and use a new one.

Comment: Magic Smoke™ escaping = dead. 100% guaranteed. What more do you want?

Comment: It is an ex-chip. It has ceased to be.

Comment: The underworld can't thank you, nor can death praise you; those who go down to the pit can't hope for your faithfulness.

Comment: A reference for the "magic smoke" referred to above:
[magic smoke](http://foldoc.org/magic%20smoke) *"(electronics, humour) A substance trapped inside integrated circuit packages that enables them to function"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chip is dead.

As you said yourself, it got hot enough to burn your finger and also burn the epoxy case (hence smoke), both of which mean it has quite literally fried.

---

In general, the answer to the question "is there a way to check if an IC with unknown condition is 100% functional?" is simply maybe.

The only way to test an IC is to try it, and if it behaves within the manufacturers specifications, then it is most likely functional - though it is not guaranteed to be.

The only way to be more sure (still not certain though) that you have a functional IC is to buy a new one. A new chip is much more likely to be functional than one of unknown condition.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm just going to toss the chip then and buy a new one.

Comment: @user2417339 You have 10 questions and have yet to accept any of the answers.  Please be polite and accept some.  8)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat is this time to start ignoring questions then?

Comment: @SolarMike Just a gentle reminder.

Comment: @stainlesssteelrat good catch I didn't realize I was leaving my questions open